# List with a lot of entries and images loaded from web -- how to not run out of memory?

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I'm trying to do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQVS1.jpg) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z295N.jpg). The layout doesn't matter all that much, what I'm after here is something that works similarly to `VirtualizingStackPanel` in WinPhone.

I've tried just loading all images from web at startup and then assigning the m to a view in the `GetView()` method of my custom `ListAdapter` but it doesn't seem like that's how it should be done on Android.

Comment: I would recommend using `RecyclerView` and `Picasso` to accomplish this. There's many ways to "Not run out of memory". I would recommend watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cfb3RAyQg4w

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll watch it in a sec, or at least parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for some image loading libraries such as glide or picasso and render the images along with your metadata in android RecyclerView instead of Listview.

Please Ref :

http://square.github.io/picasso/

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

I would recommend glide as it has the provision of restricting the app memory and cache usage. Even the configuration can be done easily.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an image loader library such as Glide or Picasso to load images optimally. Also, you'll be able to use cache them.